# pyspark - FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been using SparkSession from pyspark.sql to load a table from sql to pyspark dataframe. I am using pycharm as IDE. getting below error.
Strangely, the code worked for me in the beginning, but then somehow(without me making any changes to the python or java or pyspark settings), started getting this error.
Also, I have checked and these files exist in the mentioned path.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\neha_singh3\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\pleaserun.py", line 8, in 
.getOrCreate()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\neha_singh3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 497, in getOrCreate
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\neha_singh3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 515, in getOrCreate
SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
File "C:\Users\neha_singh3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 201, in **init**
SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
File "C:\Users\neha_singh3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 436, in _ensure_initialized
SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\neha_singh3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 100, in launch_gateway
proc = Popen(command, **popen_kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\neha_singh3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\neha_singh3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

So far I have tried:

1. Installing jdk 11
2. Using pycharm as admin
3. Uninstalling and installing again both python 3.11.7 and pycharm 2023
4. Installing python for all users
5. Installing python for my user only
6. Executing my code through CMD as admin

I know it's not related to pycharm since I am getting this error on jupyter notebook as well.
Can someone please let me know how to fix this?